# Android-Studio : Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine

Tags: android, jvm, gradle, android-studio

I have just installed Android - studio today. First I have to install jdk7 for this IDE.

After that only I was able to launch IDE.

Now When I am trying to create new project, just getting error as shown in below image.

[image]

Can anybody please help me.

What is missing from my side?

Comment: are you create or import a project?

Comment: Have tested with creating new project....

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In my case, I changed below file to modify vm heap option.

```
C:\Program Files\Android\android-studio\bin\studio.exe.vmoptions
```

I increased -Xms128m to -Xms512m and restarted Android Studio.

After that, I could go to next step.

Answer (score 19):

I found a solution to this problem on an old [vs-android issue](https://code.google.com/p/vs-android/issues/detail?can=2&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=15).

You should create a new environment variable named `_JAVA_OPTIONS`, set it to
`-Xms256m -Xmx1024m` and it should work.

Comment: thank you! Linked to your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16782564/382515

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me setting both options to -Xms512m and -Xmx512m

Answer (score 6):

I guess you have the same problem as me. I use Windows 7 32bit and therefore my Java SDK and runtime are also 32 bit.
Gradle runs in its own Java VM and Android Studio starts this VM with a heap size parameter (-Xmx1024m) of 1 GB. This is too much for my 32-bit environment and creating the JVM fails.

If I manually start Gradle with -Xmx512m as JVM option Gradle starts without problems, but so far I have not found out how to tell Android Studio to start the JVM differently while it creates a new Android project.

So currently I'm also still stuck.

thomas

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I will also try to find a solution on the same way, if it is the only issue.

Comment: Nice point about the 32 bit thing.  I've configured `C:\Program Files\Android\android-studio\bin\studio.exe.vmoptions` with the values you suggested, killed a few apps, and it worked, :-)

Answer (score 5):

1.In the Studio, navigate to
File-> Settings->Compiler

```
   In the VM Options text box, paste this line
   -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

2. Delete the existing AVD.
3. Then File->Invalidate Caches/Restart .
4. After restarting the studio, create a new AVD.
   Should work fine !

Comment: what is this file invalidate stands for?, i am having the same problem for android studio on 32 bit machine?

Comment: Studio sometimes can not take up the recent modified files, and at times try to fetch the configurations from the cache, so when you do invalidate think it like, it is clearing all the cache and fetching the current configurations you mentioned. Could you please try the above steps, worked for me and few others.See if this works for you

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution in [vs-android Issue 15: -dex: could not create the Java virtual machine](https://code.google.com/p/vs-android/issues/detail?id=15)

Follow this steps:

1. Run regedit
2. Go to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`
3. Select Environment
4. Add a new String Value and enter `_JAVA_OPTIONS` for Value name
5. Enter `-Xms256m -Xmx512m` for Value data
6. Reboot computer

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I also change below file.

```
C:\Program Files\Android\android-studio\bin\studio.exe.vmoptions
```

but I decreased -XX:MaxPermSize=350m to -XX:MaxPermSize=300m and restarted Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem. I downloaded and installed JDK 6u43 and set my JAVA_HOME and JDK_HOME environment variables to C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_43. This let me create a project.

Doesn't help if you want to use jdk7, though.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing this same issue, and I solved it by the following steps:-

1. Close android studio.
2. Go to your project folder.
3. Delete `.gradle` folder and `gradle.properties` file.
4. Now start android studio project and wait while gradle build.
   It will not show the error.