# What Type of error is it?

Tags: android, android-studio

[image: error I got]

I have installed Android Studio in my PC successfully. I run it but when I want to create a new project, I get the following error. How do I fix this?

Comment: "Could not reserve enough space for object heap" - how much memory do you have?

Comment: What is the -Xmx  value?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16619773/failed-to-import-new-gradle-project-failed-to-find-build-tools-revision-17-0-0