# What is gradle android and how to import gradle project in Eclipse Juno?

Tags: java, android, eclipse-juno, android-gradle-plugin

Gradle is a bit confusing, Can anyone explain what gradle android is ? How to integrate gradle in eclipse juno (if it is possible) ? How to import gradle project in eclipse ?

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBuild/article.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gradle is the main component of the new Android build system that was introduced with the new IDE for Android development, AndroidStudio. The [Gradle user guide](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide) is a good read.

It is possible to use the new gradle-based build system with Eclipse, just follow the steps pointed out here: 
[Is there any way to integrate Eclipse with Gradle in Android project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19912393/is-there-any-way-to-integrate-eclipse-with-gradle-in-android-project)

Answer (score 1):

Gradle is an advanced build system as well as an advanced build toolkit allowing to create custom build logic through plugins.

You can see a [user guide](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide) on gradle.