# How to import 3rd party library using Maven into Java project using Gradle?

Tags: java, maven, gradle

I want to use the [sxcml-java](https://github.com/carlos-verdes/scxml-java) library in my son's school's robotics code (currently a private repo).

The library uses Maven. I was able to successfully include the library in a test project using Maven.

However, I've just discovered that the existing robotics project code uses Gradle. I don't know either Maven or Gradle, and I haven't programmed in Java in almost 30 years.

How can I most easily use scxml-java - which itself has [external 3rd party dependencies](https://github.com/carlos-verdes/scxml-java/blob/master/pom.xml#L157-L163) — in the robotics project?

*This question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23971494/405017), but the solution there was easy because both projects were using Gradle.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided the package is published in an artifactory, which is the case (See [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.nosolojava.fsm/scxml-java-interface)), you can just include it as any other Gradle dependency (using groupId, artifactId and version), regardless of what build system was used to build it in the first place.

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.nosolojava.fsm:scxml-java-implementation:1.0.1'
}
```

If you use IntelliJ IDEA, pasting the Maven dependency block into the `build.gradle` file will automatically convert it into the Gradle dependency format like the one above.

Please note however this [does not apply to plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19642990/can-i-use-a-maven-plugin-enunciate-in-gradle), only to regular dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

## If You install your jar or third party jar into maven local repo like `~/.m2`

you can add **mavenLocal()**

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()    
    // * Require by Use JAR install to Maven Local Repo your .m2
    mavenLocal()
}
```

then  add **implementation** to **dependencies**

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:31.1-jre'
  implementation 'yourGroupId:yourArtifactId:yourVersion'
}
```

Please mapping yourGroupId , yourArtifactId,  yourVersion from your `pom.xml`

## If You only download third party jar into foler like `/home/yourName/your-libs`

you can add **configurations**

```
configurations {
    sxcml-java-lib
}
```

then add dependencies

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:31.1-jre'
  
  //sxcml-java-lib fileTree(dir: "${System.getProperty("user.home")}/libs", include: "*.jar")
  sxcml-java-lib fileTree(dir: "/home/yourName/your-libs", include: "*.jar")
}
```