# How to compile MaterialDesignLibrary to import directly in Eclipse project

Tags: android, android-support-library, material-design

How I can compile this library: [MaterialDesign](https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary#flat-button) to obtain a .jar unique file that can be used in my Android project ?
There is a way to do it ? Someone has already do it? 
I use Eclipse so I can't use gradle dependencies, Thank in advice.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot create a jar from the library because the library has resources. The .jar libraries does not support resources. 
You can try the gradle plugin for the eclipse (follow this instructions: [Is there any way to integrate Eclipse with Gradle in Android project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19912393/is-there-any-way-to-integrate-eclipse-with-gradle-in-android-project)) or download the project and try to convert to an eclipse android project...
The best solution is to use Android Studio =)