# Android application project in Eclipse and use gradle or maven to download JARS

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm using Eclipse IDE Mars and the ADT android plugin and the sdk 23, and I always encounter problems when I try to install a .JAR all the sites where I download a JAR have a sample about how to install the JAR using Maven or Gradle, I tried to install Android for Maven Eclipse 1.4.0 (m2e) plugin but had the following error `The following solutions are not available: Android for Maven Eclipse 1.4.0 (id=com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group, site=http://rgladwell.github.io/m2e-android/updates/)`.

So I tried to install gradle plugin instead to do so I followed this question:

[Is there any way to integrate Eclipse with Gradle in Android project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19912393/is-there-any-way-to-integrate-eclipse-with-gradle-in-android-project)  and I installed the Gradle IDE plugin but I don't know where to go from here since all the documentation I can find it is for too advanced users I can't find a simple tutorial in how to create an android application and use gradle to download the JARS all the info that appears is a gradle.build where you put the name of the jars similar to maven dependencies.

My questions are

1) How can I solved this problem ``The following solutions are not available: Android for Maven Eclipse 1.4.0 (id=com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group, site=http://rgladwell.github.io/m2e-android/updates/)when I try to install the maven plugin, Since I already have used Maven before and I have a lillte more experience with it than with gradle.

2) How can I use the Gradle IDE eclipse plugin to just download the JARS in my android application default project or some example about How to transform a default Android project application created by Eclipse IDE and add gradle to this project so I can download JARS. ( I don't have the Gradle_home variable in my system variables I don't know if this is necesary since if I only download the plugin).

My goal is just to use anyone of this tools  to download JARS