# RecycleView not working after updating support libs

Tags: android, material-design, android-recyclerview, android-support-library

I have implemented RecyclerView in my android project, Which was working fine when I was using Android Support Library version 23.0.1.then I had to update my support Library for some other functionality so I updated my Support Library to 23.1.1. Then as libraries were updated I have deleted previous libraries from eclipse and re-import them and added them to project and cleaned workspace. after that I am getting following compile time error
"The type android.support.v4.view.ScrollingView cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files"
whereas there is no compile time error in any of the methods which I override from RecyclerView Library.

```
package com.palasha.tccnetmanager.views;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

public class CustomRecyclerView extends RecyclerView {

    public CustomRecyclerView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomRecyclerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomRecyclerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean fling(int velocityX, int velocityY) {
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) getLayoutManager();
        int firstVisibleView = linearLayoutManager
                .findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
        if (firstVisibleView != -1)
            if (velocityX > 0)
                smoothScrollToPosition(firstVisibleView + 1);
            else if (firstVisibleView != 0)
                smoothScrollToPosition(firstVisibleView - 1);
            else
                smoothScrollToPosition(0);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After wasting some time on this i just fixed it, following this steps:

Remove all support library from your workspace.

Import the support library again(android-support-v7-appcompat) to your workspace.

Go to libs directory of your library v7 which you have imported and delete the "android-support-v4.jar" file.

Left click the project library imported Select "Android Tools" and then click to "Add support library..."

Wait until process gets finish.

Go to your project properties-> Android-> click add-> select android-support-v7-appcompat, click Apply.

Clean the project.

Left click to your project-> properties-> Java Build Path-> libraries

Click "Add JARs.."

Go to android-support-v7-appcompat project's libs directory and select android-support-v4.jar file. Click OK.

Again clean project.

Now import RecyclerView Library and add to project. Again clean it.

This is how I come out of this problem.

Answer (score 2):

The version of **android-support-v4.jar** you are using may be old,replace it with the one in

```
sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\libs\android-support-v4.jar
```

Comment: how about using gradle instead of jars?

Comment: @WarrenFaith As far as I know we cannot use gradle in eclipse. if you know the way, please suggest.

Comment: Not true: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19912393/is-there-any-way-to-integrate-eclipse-with-gradle-in-android-project

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this for recylerview in android studio

    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0'

or find here

    \sdk\extras\android\m
```

2repository\com\android\support\recyclerview-v7

Comment: Ya I know this, but we are developing this project in eclipse. and currently no plan to port this in android studio. so suggest some way for eclipse.

Comment: yes you can find the recyclerview jar file from this path..\sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\recyclerview-v7

Comment: still getting same problem :( with this library also

Comment: Why you extend the recyclerview

Comment: <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/layout"
        android:layout_below="@id/header"
        android:background="@drawable/login_layout_corner"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

Comment: you can directly add the recyclerview in android layout and find the view in activity

Comment: I wanted fling() for changing the scroll behaviour, that is another thing, firstly the problem is recycler view is not getting recognized.

Comment: yes u need to add the library then its can detect and you need the target version to the max like 22 or 23

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95334/discussion-between-palash-agrawal-and-rohit-heera).