# Build two different apk using one single code in android eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, build.gradle, package-name

I am still working with Eclipse to develop android applications. Now there is a situation where I am supposed to build 2 different applications (You can consider as free and non-free version apk) using same app-code. I have got thousands of links regarding `build.gradle` and `application package-name` and others on google, but I don't how to build/use it in Eclipse.

> Another question I have is how to point to 2 different images
>   based on different application.?

Comment: Consider using Android Studio with gradle builds that make this very easy using build flavors.

Comment: The only real answers (today) to your questions are "Use Android Studio".

Comment: I suggest you to migrate your project to Android Studio and use Flavors. Depending on the dependencies of your project, the migration can be more or less harder, but totally worth it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to release two different build (paid and free). You need to change the package name. Just goto the manifest file.
For example: for free version

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.android.free">
```

and similarly for paid version

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.android.paid">
```

Alternatively, I will recommend you to use In app purchase feature and release only build

Comment: It is working well for 2 different applications. Can you tell how to pick 2 different images for 2 different apks to display at one place?

Comment: Yes, you can create multiple images of apk from a single place. In given link, there is detailed article about it
http://developer.android.com/training/multiple-apks/api.html

Comment: without putting code and resource in project library? something like I am able to choose `res` folder of application.?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. [Is there any way to integrate Eclipse with Gradle in Android project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19912393/is-there-any-way-to-integrate-eclipse-with-gradle-in-android-project).. There is no simple answer for this question.. Either you use eclipse with gradle and set two flavours with different in your build.gradle

```
productFlavors {
    free {
        applicationId 'your.package.name.free'
    }
    paid {
        applicationId 'your.package.name.paid'
    }
}
```

or else just copy your project twice and change package name. If you want to upload both your apps in play store then you need two different package names.