# I want to use Fabric/Crashlytics with ADT / Eclipse

Tags: android, adt, eclipse-adt, twitter-fabric

I have not migrated my project to Android Studio yet, but I still want to use Fabric/Crashlytics to manage crashes of my app. I am using the Android Developer Tools (ADT) 23.

I tried the Fabrics eclipse plugin and it installs and starts fine. Then I login and the plugin presents a "Select kit to install" dialog. But the buttons are inactive and they only say "checkin...". After a few seconds I am getting the login screen again. I tried a few times it doesnt work that way, since the eclipse plugin is discontinued i guess i can not hope for any support.

So is there a way to download an sdk or a java lib somewhere and perform all the necessary steps myself?

Here is a step by step to do it manually and it seems easy, if your setup has gradle support:
https://www.fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/install

But I dont have Android Studio, so the build.gradle is no good to me.
I added a few SDKs and libraries of other companies to my project and I never had so many problems like this.

Maybe someone can aid me to the right path?

Comment: If you are planning on migrating to Android Studio, I would suggest starting sooner rather than later. Not to be "that guy" but it is the only fully supported IDE for Android development.

Comment: I know and you are right, but migrating to Android Studio will open a new can of worms which I want to avoid for now.

Comment: Here is the step-by-step instruction on using gradle in ADT: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19912393/is-there-any-way-to-integrate-eclipse-with-gradle-in-android-project. But methinks that switching to AS will open a smaller can of worms.