# Firebase Storage in android eclipse project

Tags: android, eclipse, firebase, firebase-storage

I have an android project on Eclipse and I want to use Firebase 'Cloud Storage' within it.

using Android Studio, I add Firebase to my app by using the Firebase Assistant and Connect to Firebase, then I add the dependencies for Cloud Storage to my build.gradle file [`compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.4.2'`] and it works fine.

while the android project on Eclipse hasn't build.gradle file. So how can I install firebase Cloud Storage for eclipse and add it to my project?

Comment: You can add Gradle to your Eclipse install, or you can import Eclipse project to Android Studio. Other options are much more difficult

Comment: Eclipse isn't really supported by Play services or Firebase.  You should seriously consider switching to gradle and Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to

1. [use gradle with eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19912393/is-there-any-way-to-integrate-eclipse-with-gradle-in-android-project) or
2. [download the firebase jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.firebase/firebase-client-android) and add it to your libs folder

I don't know how far you'll get with 2. because you might need to apply the [google services gradle plugin](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin) to get everything running.

If you're thinking about going with option 1., you'd probably be better off converting the project into an Android Studio project anyways, which I'd strongly recommend, because Eclipse is not supported anymore since [june 2015](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2015/06/an-update-on-eclipse-android-developer.html).