# Conditionally excluding java files from build/apk

Tags: java, android, eclipse, build

I would like to create a limited version of my Android app, excluding about a dozen class files from the final APK.  Of course, I can just move them to a different folder, or use "Build Path > Exclude".  I am wondering if there were a more elegant way of achieving this, via a single flag somewhere in the project.  Any ideas?

Comment: You can maybe have 2 projects with a library project in common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the ways is to use build flavors in the [new gradle based build system](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide). It is an [elegant solution and recommended by Android developer site](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-build.html#workBuildVariants) . With Build Flavors, you can share common set of files between two versions of the same app, and customize it as needed. For additional details on how to do this [please see this SO question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16737006/using-build-flavors-structuring-source-folders-and-build-gradle-correctly)

You can use gradle build with eclipse too, please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17107014/is-it-possible-to-use-the-gradle-build-system-for-android-with-eclipse) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19912393/is-there-any-way-to-integrate-eclipse-with-gradle-in-android-project).

Comment: you can use grade android build with eclipse too, please see my edit.