# Building Android app with Jenkins & Gradle

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle

I'm a devops engineer, and my company is building their first Android app.  For all of our other projects, we've used Jenkins to handle builds.

I've read quite a few tutorials on getting android building on Jenkins and they all seem to rely on Gradle.  I'd like to get out in front of the devs a bit and start the job.  Is it possible that the app that they build doesn't support Gradle?  What scenarios are those, so I can influence decisions?

Maybe Gradle isn't the latest thing, if not, what is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible that the app that they build doesn't support Gradle?

It is possible that they are *not currently building* the app with Gradle, but highly unlikely that the app could *not* be built with Gradle.

> What scenarios are those, so I can influence decisions?

The most likely scenario where they are not building with Gradle, is that they use the Eclipse IDE to develop the app. Eclipse projects have historically been built more often with Ant or Maven. But an Eclipse project *can* be built with Gradle. That said, configuring an Android project to be built with Gradle is *not* a requirement to build that project with Jenkins. Ant, Maven, and other build tools play nice with Jenkins also. So, if your dev team is using a build tool other than Gradle, that shouldn't be a blocker for you. You should be able to accommodate them, if that's going to cause less friction.

> Maybe Gradle isn't the latest thing, if not, what is?

I'm not sure about *latest*, but Gradle does currently have a lot of momentum as the build tool of choice for Android projects because it is the default build tool for Android Studio (which is positioned to replace Eclipse as the default Android IDE).

---

So, my advice would be to ask your dev team what IDE and build tool they are currently using, and go from there... (if they use Eclipse and you want to build with Gradle: [Is it possible to use the Gradle build system for Android with Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17107014/is-it-possible-to-use-the-gradle-build-system-for-android-with-eclipse))

Source: At the company I work for, I develop two Android apps and make daily builds with Jenkins. A few months ago I switched from Eclipse (Ant) to Android Studio (Gradle).

I hope this was helpful. I have not answered many questions on here so I'm not entirely sure I'm doing it right. :)