# How can I tell which IDE an Android project was made with?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, gradle

For example this project. I see it has Gradle files, but a quick search says Eclipse has a Gradle plugin as well.

https://github.com/sephiroth74/HorizontalVariableListView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Gradle** is a building tool. It has plugins for **Eclipse**, **IntelliJ**, **Android Studio** and **Netbeans**. So you won't be able to tell which **IDE** an Android project is made with from just a gradle file. Some project structures vary, for Eclipse projects and IntelliJ ones, you can find easily differences between them if you are familiar with both. But some are not explicitly, for IntelliJ projects and Android Studio ones.

BTW, do **IDE**s matter? The App you are building does, I am afraid.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. Can you please elaborate on the differences between Eclipse and IntelliJ? Is it just the .classpath & .project as mentioned by PageNotFound? Or more the fact that few people would use Gradle with Eclipse?

Comment: Talk is cheap. I think you'd better download them and create test project to find out what is the difference of file tree between them. You need to do it by your self.

Comment: You are right. Will do just that, thanks. btw, you meant **N**etbeans, right?

Comment: It's NetBeans, sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

The Android build system is built on top of gradle:

https://developer.android.com/tools/building/plugin-for-gradle.html

So that means that just plain gradle is not enough to build an Android project.

As ADT never used gradle and Google has ended Eclipse support, you can be reasonably confident that an Android gradle project was made using Android Studio.

Comment: according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17107014/is-it-possible-to-use-the-gradle-build-system-for-android-with-eclipse, it seems to be possible to use gradle to build the project.

Comment: Hm, well that's good to know at least. Seems pretty convoluted tho.

Answer (score 1):

[Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/tools/studio/index.html), which is developed based on IntelliJ. It uses [gradle](https://gradle.org/) to build the project.

If a project contains `.classpath` or `.project`, it should be made by Eclipse. Or it should be made by android studio. A project made by android studio can not be imported into eclipse.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but I am asking **how** to tell it, now what it was made with..