# Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536 in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, dalvik, dex

I'm developing an application on Eclipse. In which I need to use the following `libraries`

1) AppCompact

2) Google Play Services

3) LiveSDK

4) json.jar

When I try to run my project it gave this error.

`Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536`
`Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536`

Even I have remove the libraies from `Java Buid Path`  but still I got this error.

I have also used the progaurd but error is not resolved. Here is my progarud file

**project.properties**

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt

# Project target.
target=android-22
android.library.reference.1=./workspace2/google-play-services_lib
android.library.reference.2=./workspace2/LiveSdk
android.library.reference.3=./android/workspace2/appcompat_v7
```

**proguard-project.txt**

-optimizationpasses 5
    -dontusemixedcaseclassnames
    -dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
    -dontpreverify
    -verbose
    -optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

```
-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}
-keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle {
    protected Object[][] getContents();
}

-keep public class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable {
    public static final *** NULL;
}

-keepnames @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName class *
-keepclassmembernames class * {
    @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName *;
}

-keepnames class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    public static final ** CREATOR;
}
```

Help me !!

Comment: clear your `yourProject-->bin-->dexedlibs folder` and then remove all `libraries` and then add all the `libraries` again

Comment: @MD still got same error

Comment: Check this link - https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/tools/building/multidex.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to execute dex: method ID not in \[0, 0xffff\]: 65536](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209831/unable-to-execute-dex-method-id-not-in-0-0xffff-65536)

Comment: @JesusFreke, That will not resolved my problem. Answers given on that link far for `AndroidStudio` not for `Eclipse`.

Comment: Yes, the solutions as given in that question are to use multidex or proguard. The choice of IDE doesn't change the fact that these are the 2 options you have for resolving this issue.

Answer (score 2):

You have exceeded the 65k methods limit. 
So what you want is enable multidex or to have less than 65k methods in your app + libraries.

There is a multidex support library but it is not supported by ant or eclipse.
https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/HQM7qeosJoF

And you could also load individual Play Services APIs because you probably don't need them all
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

but you would still need AS and gradle.

Apparently you can use gradle with eclipse but I never tried it

[Is it possible to use the Gradle build system for Android with Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17107014/is-it-possible-to-use-the-gradle-build-system-for-android-with-eclipse)

My advice is to migrate to Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

Your getting this error because your exceeding the 65k limit.
Check https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Comment: I know this. But wants any solution.

Comment: @SandeepSingh Add multidex support to  your app. In that link, it shows how to do it. I have done the same in Android studio and it works fine.  Not sure on if it's different on eclipse.