# FirebaseUI eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, firebase, firebaseui

Is there any way to use **FirebaseUI** in **Eclipse** for my android app?

Specifically, can I use this repo : https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android in eclipse in anyway?

Note : Am using eclipse not Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the Firebase supports Eclipse or not. But anyway, you might consider using gradle build system in Eclipse too.

Here's a [nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20798531/3145960) explaining how to use two build system (Eclipse + Gradle) at a time.

See the updates of the answer.

I'm just quoting from that answer.

> Instead of creating IDE-specific Android/Gradle models, we decided to
>   have an IDE-agnostic representation of a Gradle project. This way, we
>   have a single source of information that is easier to maintain. IDE
>   integration will be implemented as a plug-in for each supported IDE
>   (in our case, Eclipse and IDEA.) The main benefit of this approach is
>   that we can release the Gradle plug-in independently of the IDE
>   integration plug-ins. For example, we can ship a new version of the
>   Eclipse plug-in that has several bug fixes, without affecting the
>   Gradle side of Android.

So looks like, gradle model is not IDE specific. You might consider having a eclipse plugin for gradle integration.

Comment: Well, is there still a difference between Android Studio 's gradle and eclipse's one after Gradle released "Buildship for Eclipse " ? How would I know?

Answer (score 0):

**Maintainer of FirebaseUI here**

FirebaseUI relies on a number of advanced Android library and Gradle features to work correctly.  For this reason we can only support users in Android Studio, we don't test in Eclipse and don't plan to.  Sorry for the inconvenience!