# Where do I add android support library v7 to build.gradle?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-support-library

I am trying to use action bar in android 2.2, but i cant find **build.gradle** in my project?  Can anybody help me please?

Link is here:http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

```
Make sure you have downloaded the Android Support Repository using the SDK Manager.
**Open the build.gradle file for your application.**
Add the support library feature project identifier to the dependencies section. For example, to include the appcompat project add compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+" to the dependencies section, as shown in the following example:
dependencies {
    ...
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+"
}
```

Comment: Is your project an Eclipse project or an Android Studio one?

Comment: android studio and i download android support files from sdk/extras part

Comment: Check out similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18006641/import-of-eclipse-project-into-android-studio-using-build-gradle-file-fails

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio you can search for a file. So, in Windows try `ctrl + shift + n` or in Mac try `cmd + shift + o`. Then type `build.gradle` and the file will show up in the search results. Look for the block `dependencies` and add the support library there, like so

```
 dependencies {
     ...
     compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.0'
 }
```

If you want to know more about gradle check the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-build.html).