# Could not execute build using gradle installation

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

When I try to compile my application, I get the following error:

```
Gradle: 
FAILURE: Could not determine which tasks to execute.

* What went wrong:
Task 'assembleDebug' not found in root project 'Project'.

* Try:
Run gradle tasks to get a list of available tasks.


Could not execute build using Gradle installation 'C:\Users\[username]\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-1.6-bin\72srdo3a5eb3bic159kar72vok\gradle-1.6'.
```

Now I have been searching around on stackoverflow and other websites, and I am not the only person experiencing this issue. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16585869/android-studio-error-installing-gradle/16600297#16600297)  solution, aswell as restarting the program several times, and reinstalling Android Studio entirely. Still I'm getting the same error. I also tried manually deleting the "gradle-1.6" folder from the

```
'C:\Users\[username]\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-1.6-bin\72srdo3a5eb3bic159kar72vok\'
```

folder, and putting the [newest version](http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.6-bin.zip) of gradle into the folder manually.

Nothing helped. Still getting the error.

Comment: Hi. Can you share your project structure, settings.gradle and build.gradle files please ?

Answer (score 1):

Doublecheck your gradle-installation to see if its properly set up.

- [Installation guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16619773/failed-to-import-new-gradle-project-failed-to-find-build-tools-revision-17-0-0/17447972#17447972)
- And then run `gradle build`
- If problem still presist, please provide us with your build.gradle files.

Comment: I actually tried this solution at the time, but it didn't help. Something else did, because it suddenly worked.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, once, the JDK's location was not defined correctly. The error did not tell this, but fixing the JDK's location corrected the error.

Answer (score 0):

Re-adding my JDK location fixes this error for me. I open File->Project Structure and re-enter the JDK location by deleting the last directory in the path (Home) and then re-typing it. The path looks exactly the same as before, but the error goes away and I can build from Android Studio again.

Definitely a bug in Android Studio, it seems like the path is getting corrupted at some level.