# Update Android built tool To 18.0

Tags: android, build.gradle

I used to use Android Built-Tools 17 to build a project, now the tools I have updated to 18.0, Now I change build.gradle :

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "18.0.1"
}
```

when I run this, it was wrong, Gradle: Execution failed for task ':HandyHis:compileDebugAidl'.

> failed to find Build Tools revision 18.0.0

What should I do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Failed to import new Gradle project: failed to find Build Tools revision 17.0.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16619773/failed-to-import-new-gradle-project-failed-to-find-build-tools-revision-17-0-0)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look in the SDK Manager what is your highest Android SDK Build-tools version, and copy this version number in your project "build.gradle" file in the android/buildToolsversion property (for me, version was "18.1.1").

Hope it help!