# Failed to find Build Tools revision 23.0.1

Tags: android, linux, react-native

I am trying to build my first app with react-native.

I am following these 2 tutorial:

- https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#content
- https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html

I am sure that I installed all the requirements from the second link but when I try running my app with `react-native run-android`, I get the following error:

[image: Error]

I executed this command while running genymotion.

This is all that I have installed in Android SDK:

[image]

[image]

I tried to install Android build tools 23.0.1 but I get this error:

[image]

What should I do?

Comment: Solved with https://stackoverflow.com/a/68430992/14784590

Answer (score 138, accepted):

I faced the same problem and I solved it doing the following:

Go to /home/***[USER]***/Android/Sdk/tools
and execute:

> $android list sdk -a

Which will show a list like:

1. Android SDK Tools, revision 24.0.2
2. Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 23.0.2
3. **Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 23.0.1**

... and many more

Then, execute the command (attention! at your computer the third option may be different):

> $android update sdk -a -u -t **3**

It will install the 23.0.1 SDK Platform-tools components.

Try to build your project again.

Comment: worked for me - android studio is installed at ~/Library/Android/sdk/tools on mac

Comment: It installed `revision 25.0.1` not 23.0.1

Comment: @LukasLiesis From the first command `android list sdk -a` check what number 23.0.1 gets. It will change over time. Yesterday it was 12. So the install command was `android update sdk -a -u -t 12`

Comment: @Manwe how can i get that number? P.s. already installed required version with sdk manager, but still, for future googlers :-)

Comment: @LukasLiesis `android list sdk -a` lists a lot on the screen. Lines start with NUMBER- . It's one of those. Most likely 12 today. If you are a linux user you can find it with grep: `android list sdk -a | grep 23.0.1`

Comment: Thanks, by the way ./android is deprecated, now in `/home/[USER]/Android/Sdk/tools/bin` you can run `./sdkmanager --list` to get the same result
After that I fixed it by finding a build-tools version that was matching a version found in `sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7`

Comment: You should do this by interface panel like @Dary explained bellow

Comment: Updating for CLI use the parent directory of `tools` directory must be named as `cmdline-only`. The `tools` is the content downloadable from "Command line tools only" session in https://developer.android.com/studio?hl=pt-br#downloads. In case `sdkmanager` is in `/home/[USER]/Android/Sdk/cmdline-only/tools/bin` as this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49357554/5382576

Answer (score 160):

You should install Android SDK Build Tools 23.0.1 via Android SDK. Don't forget to check `Show Packages Details`.

[image]

Comment: I had to remove build build tools using SDK manager firstly and then add it again. It fixed the issue.

Comment: Hi, for future googlers: if the version you are looking for does not exist press the box Show Package Details

Comment: I had to install both the platform (details + Google API) and the tools.

Answer (score 45):

Either install v23.0.1 of the build tools (the fifth row in your screenshot), or change your code to use the build tools version you already have installed (v23.0.3). This can be specified in your app's `build.gradle` file:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        ...
    }
}
```

As per duncanc4's comment below,

> The build.gradle file you want to edit is in the android/app folder
>   within your project directory.

Comment: i tried installing it but i get the error in the last image. How do i choose what build tool version to use?

Comment: He's using react-native, so i'm not sure how much access he's got to the build.gradle file.

Comment: Interesting, the build is still obviously using gradle under the hood (see the terminal snapshot) so I would expect it to be hiding in there somewhere...

Comment: With **Android Studio 3.0.1** and **Gradle 4.3.1** there is no `buildToolsVersion` property, so I added it into `defaultConfig` (in the same file) and it stopped showing the error.

Comment: As of v3.0.0 of the Android Gradle plugin, the build tools version is automatically determined based on the plugin version (but can be overridden, I believe).

Answer (score 18):

The error you're getting seems to be related to system's permissions, since it's not able to create a folder.

Try running the sdk-manager using root (with `su` or `sudo` commands).

Answer (score 10):

I had this error:

> Failed to find Build Tools revision 23.0.2

When you got updated/installed:

1. **Android SDK Build Tools**
2. **Android SDK Tools**

Change version number in `build.gradle`

*FROM*

```
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
```

*TO*

```
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
```

[How to find what Build Tools version you have](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16619773/failed-to-import-new-gradle-project-failed-to-find-build-tools-revision-0-0/39068538#39068538)

Answer (score 8):

Check your $ANDROID_HOME, sometimes is /usr/local/opt/android, but it's not your install sdk path, change it and fix this problem

Comment: Thankyou so much. I've been going in circles for hours between `Failed to find Build Tools revision *.0.0` and `install build tools *.0.0 and sync project`. On Windows, I added ANDROID_HOME="C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Android\sdk" as a system variable. Finally works.

Answer (score 7):

Nothing helped until I found this solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/39068538/3995091

In Android SDK, the build tools with the correct version where shown as installed, but still I got the same error saying they couldn't be found. When I used the above solution, I found out they were indeed not installed, although Android SDK thought they were. Installing them solved it for me.

Answer (score 7):

While running react-native In case you have installed 23.0.3 and it is asking for 23.0.1 simply in your application project directory.  Open `anroid/app/build.gradle` and change `buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In the **Gradle Console** (link available in the window bottom right), you have two tabs: the error is shown in **Gradle Build** tab. Click on the **Gradle Sync** tab, then click on the **Install Build Tools XX.X.X and sync project** link. This will download the build version required by your project.

You may also change your project SDK version but you don't always have this option if it is imposed.

Answer (score 2):

If you already install the correct **Android SDK Platform-Tools** (Build Tool) and you still get an error, try to invalidate the cache; **File -> Invalidate caches / Restart....**

Answer (score 0):

On my system, Android SDK Manager showed `/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk` as the SDK path, when `$ANDROID_HOME` was `/Users/james/Library/Android/sdk`. I just added a symlink for the correct build tools version.

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions: You have to instal the required buildToolVersion or set it as described above.
**Notice that** if you are trying to set the `buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"` using Android Studio 3.0 or more it won't work until you remove all builversion you have keeping just one last version you use. 
I read this somewhere else and this works for me.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says 
Failed to find build Tools revision 23.0.1 
This means that in your project you have used 
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
So,You need to download the exact same version this makes the error disappear

```
**Step 1:**
GO to Tools and click SDK Manager
**Step 2:**
you can see SDK Platforms ,SDK Tools and SDK update Sites
**Step3:**
Click SDK Tools and click show package details
**Step 4:**
Select the version that you have mentioned in your Project 

These Steps has solved my issue.
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone can't build their downloaded source code (probably google codelabs source code) with Android Studio, try simply remove the `buildToolsVersion` from the `build.gradle` file, and `Android Studio` will build the project with it's default latest `buildToolVersion`

¯_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

**Each version of the [Android Gradle Plugin](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin?buildsystem=cmake#updating-gradle) now has a default version of the build tools.**

So, probably you specified build tool version explicitly in the build file.
Just remove `buildToolsVersion = "x.y.z"` from your *build.gradle* script.

If, for some reason, you need that specific revision, follow [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39828902/8583692).

Answer (score -3):

Just install it from Android Studio ;)
[image]