# react-native run-android Starting JS server... Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug

Tags: android, node.js, react-native, sdk, genymotion

After 
react-native init Project
i do : 
cd Project and
react-native run-android 
my version is : nodejs v6.9.5
emulateur genymotion api 23 
I have this error :

```
Starting JS server...
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> failed to find Build Tools revision 23.0.1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 4.309 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to find Build Tools revision 23.0.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36683726/failed-to-find-build-tools-revision-23-0-1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install Build Tools revision 23.0.1 on SDK