# Android studio failed to build tools after updating to 3.0 from 2.3 stable channel

Tags: android, android-studio-2.3, android-studio-3.0

I just updated my android studio from 2.3 to 3.0 from stable channel.

But I was getting this error

```
Failed to find Build Tools revision 26.0.2 Install Build Tools 26.0.2 and sync project
```

I do tried to install this but still failing to resolve

Comment: If you click on that error it will install it for you. You can verify in SDK Manage if it's installed. Then update in your `build.gradle` file `buildToolsVersion` to `26.0.2`

Comment: Same for me, I got the error "no package available"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to find Build Tools revision 23.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36683726/failed-to-find-build-tools-revision-23-0-1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open SDK manager to check installed buildtool revision version:

[image]

for example, I have version 27.0.3 installed.

Then add `buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'` in `build.gradle`:

[image]

Comment: Manually specifying the buildToolsVersion in build.gradle works for me, thanks! Any idea why does Android Studio insists to use 26.0.2 and won't automatically pick up the newer installed version?

Comment: I do not really know this. Maybe it's somewhere available in android studio or it has downloaded the default configuration in gradle. That's the publisher's fault

Comment: Seems to be vaguely related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48508849/build-failing-in-travis-due-to-multidex-android-bug?

Answer (score 0):

You can install any version of build tools manually.
Please go to Preferences > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK. Then select "SDK Tools" pane and be sure to check "Show package details" below the list. Then you can install additional versions of **Android SDK Build-Tools**. Voila!

[image: Android SDK install 26.0.2 tools]