# Build failing in Travis due to multidex/android bug?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, travis-ci, android-multidex

We are not using build tools "26.0.2" in our project. In fact, doing a `grep -RF "26.0.2" . | grep -v android-profile` on our project directory does not return anything except for

```
./CBSandbox/build/intermediates/multi-dex/release/components.flags:-libraryjars /home/gabor/Android/Sdk/build-tools/26.0.2/lib/shrinkedAndroid.jar
./CBSandbox/build/intermediates/multi-dex/debug/components.flags:-libraryjars /home/gabor/Android/Sdk/build-tools/26.0.2/lib/shrinkedAndroid.jar
```

That in itself is bogus though, and it causes Travis to fail our build (`Failed to find Build Tools revision 26.0.2` since our `.travis.yml` specifies `ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION=27.0.3` which we actually use). **Is it a known multidex bug that an earlier tools version is pulled during multidexing?** Note also that it's not during proguarding as CBSandbox has `minifyEnabled false` in its build file (`-libraryjars` in the output made me think of proguard).

We use the latest version of the gradle plugin which [defaults to the latest build tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html#3-0-0). But even if we manually specify the build tools, it still tries to pull an older version during multidex.

*Edit:* the build is still failing in Travis, but locally and in the Travis debug environment it succeeds:

```
travis@travis-job-76d0d0f4-b465-4926-b6fd-6496bbea6835:~/build/ChartBoost/android-sdk$ ./gradlew :CBSandbox:assemble
...
Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 26.0.2 in /usr/local/android-sdk/licenses
License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 26.0.2 accepted.
Preparing "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 26.0.2 (revision: 26.0.2)".
"Install Android SDK Build-Tools 26.0.2 (revision: 26.0.2)" ready.
Installing Android SDK Build-Tools 26.0.2 in /usr/local/android-sdk/build-tools/26.0.2
"Install Android SDK Build-Tools 26.0.2 (revision: 26.0.2)" complete.
"Install Android SDK Build-Tools 26.0.2 (revision: 26.0.2)" finished.
...
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 3m 3s
```

So I guess it's both a Travis bug (fails on the UI while succeeding via SSH) and an Android tools bug (pulls older build tools without asking for that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add the link to the known Multidex bug and reproduce the bug in an open sample project.

Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48097228/1009132), perhaps it helps.

you can add both in `.travis.yml` file:

```
android:
 components:
  - build-tools-26.0.2
  - build-tools-27.0.3
```

And manually specify the build tools version in your `build.gradle` file:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
```

I'm not sure if you are already doing it:

> But even if we manually specify the build tools, it still tries to
>   pull an older version during multidex.

Comment: Thanks, specifying `- build-tools-26.0.2` solves this. (Still weird though that it's required. I should try to create a bug report for it.)

Comment: Thanks, adding 'build-tools-26.0.2' resolve build issue. :)