# Failed to find Build Tools Revision 23.0.3

Tags: android

```
In sdk/build-tools folder i have
22.0.1
24.0.0
24.0.1
25.0.1
26.0.0
```

I have imported a project which has gradle:2.2.2
Error is Failed to build tools revision 23.0.3
**How can i resolve this issue without installing build tools 23.0.3**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to find Build Tools revision 23.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36683726/failed-to-find-build-tools-revision-23-0-1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit the build.gradle app file and change the `buildToolsVersion` to the version you have

Answer (score 0):

1. Find build-tools version you have already installed
2. finding build-tools location (C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools)
   ex:  [finding build-tools location for pic help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTBm8.png)
3. in this location build-tools version is 28.0.2
4. Open **build.gradle** file add  **buildToolsVersion "28.0.2"** after  compileSdkVersion 28
5. Now synchronize your project 
   [click here for picture help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2ejW.png)

   6. check the dependencies {
      // the code in this block should match build tools version
      }
   7. clean project
      8.re build it