# Android Studio build tools not found error

Tags: android, android-studio

Everything works as expected when creating a new project in android studio but when an already existing project is imported, error

> "No installed build tools found. Please install version 19.0.1 or
>   higher"

is shown. I have set the environment variables correctly.
 **What could be wrong?**

Comment: Check if the gradle options in setting is not selected to offline

Comment: Add a screenshot of your android studio window where it shows the error.

Comment: check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39828902/3974530

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

1. Either install the required `buildToolVersion`. (In your case 19.0.1).

   You can just press on button `Install`. Which appear with this error.
2. Or if you don't want to collect bunch of `buildToolVersion`. Then use one already existing in your sdk.

   In this case you will follow these steps.

(1) First find existing `buildToolVersion`. Either find in your old project app level `build.gradle` or you can see that in **`sdkFolder>build-tools`**. In my case it is `E:\Khemraj\AndroidDND\Sdk\build-tools`

(2) Then replace `buildToolVersion` in app level `build.gradle` with already installed `build-Tool`.

(3) You have to reopen that project. (Because just sync does not work in this case for now (Possibly a bug of Android Studio))

**Things to be considered**

- Offline mode should be disabled in case of installing new build-tool. (File>Setting>Search for offline). Disable Offline mode.
- Make sure to reopen project if you change `buildToolVersion`.

Comment: I have a total of 9 build tools version above 19.0.1 already installed. I changed the root build.gradle to one of those versions, closed and opened the project. Still not working ;(

Comment: Change 19.0.1 with one you have. Then reopen project. I am sure it will work, It is a common problem that every android developer face daily.

Comment: Now the final solution is update all the things to latest.

Comment: Inside app level build.gradle> update buildToolVersion, compileSdkVersion, all android:support versions.

Comment: In your project level build.gradle> update `com.android.tools.build:gradle` version.

Comment: In your `gradle.wrapper.properties` update gradle version distributionUrl.

Comment: Then you will not have any issue. But you can face some deprecated method in your project.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174947/discussion-between-jaison-mathew-and-khemraj).