# Ionic Build throws the following error: "could not find any matches for com.android.tools.build:gradle:+"

Tags: android, ionic-framework, gradle, ionic3

I'm developing an Ionic app and my builds were working fine two days ago, but suddenly today they're failing.

It seems it's about the FMC dependencies, since one of them is         `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:+'` and the error I'm getting is `Could not find any matches for com.android.tools.build:gradle:+`.

Plus I'm getting this message:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/patricio/infomigra_app/platforms/android/build.gradle' line: 95
```

And the line 95 is where it tries to apply the FCM plugin with the following command: `apply from: "cordova-plugin-fcm/stableapp-FCMPlugin.gradle"`.

The complete error I'm getting is:

```
ANDROID_HOME=/home/patricio/Android/Sdk
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
Reading build config file: /home/patricio/infomigra_app/build.json
Reading the keystore from: /home/patricio/infomigra_app/infomigra.keystore
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Failed to notify ProjectEvaluationListener.afterEvaluate(), but primary configuration failure takes precedence.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: buildToolsVersion is not specified.
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:173)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.createAndroidTasks(BasePlugin.java:645)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10.call(BasePlugin.java:608)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10.call(BasePlugin.java:605)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:156)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:120)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$createTasks$1(BasePlugin.java:603)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:93)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:82)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:79)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:30)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy15.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:82)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.doConfigure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:76)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.access$000(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:33)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$1.execute(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:53)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$1.execute(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:61)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:628)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:129)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:35)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:60)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:38)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:161)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:158)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:119)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:102)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:71)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/patricio/infomigra_app/platforms/android/build.gradle' line: 95

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration 'classpath'.
   > Could not find any matches for com.android.tools.build:gradle:+ as no versions of com.android.tools.build:gradle are available.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/maven-metadata.xml
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/
         file:/home/patricio/.m2/repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/maven-metadata.xml
         file:/home/patricio/.m2/repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/
     Required by:
         unspecified:unspecified:unspecified

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2.095 secs
/home/patricio/infomigra_app/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Failed to notify ProjectEvaluationListener.afterEvaluate(), but primary configuration failure takes precedence.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: buildToolsVersion is not specified.
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:173)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.createAndroidTasks(BasePlugin.java:645)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10.call(BasePlugin.java:608)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10.call(BasePlugin.java:605)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:156)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:120)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$createTasks$1(BasePlugin.java:603)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:93)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:82)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:79)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:30)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy15.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:82)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.doConfigure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:76)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.access$000(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:33)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$1.execute(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:53)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$1.execute(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:61)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:628)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:129)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:35)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:60)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:38)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:161)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:158)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:119)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:102)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:71)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/patricio/infomigra_app/platforms/android/build.gradle' line: 95

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration 'classpath'.
   > Could not find any matches for com.android.tools.build:gradle:+ as no versions of com.android.tools.build:gradle are available.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/maven-metadata.xml
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/
         file:/home/patricio/.m2/repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/maven-metadata.xml
         file:/home/patricio/.m2/repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/
     Required by:
         unspecified:unspecified:unspecified

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

What can I do? I already tried to change the `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:+'` to other versions, but the error I've got are the same always.

Answer (score 0):

```
cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-fcm
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-fcm
```

In platforms> android> cordova-plugin-fcm> xxxxx-FCMPlugin.gradle

```
dependencies {
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:+'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
}
```

In plugins> cordova-plugin-fcm> plugin.xml

```
 <framework src="com.google.firebase:firebase-core:+" />
 <framework src="com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:+" />
```

In platforms> android> project.properties

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.4.2
com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.2
com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.2
```

finally, build
ionic cordova build android

source here [enter link description here](https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm/issues/319)

Comment: I did exactly that and nothing happened, still got the same error

Comment: @OiciTrap posted other solution dont forget to rm and add the plaform again after those steps

Answer (score 0):

Comment out these lines in the FCMPlugin.gradle file (inside /plugins/cordova-plugin-fcm/src/android).

```
// classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
// apply plugin: com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin
```

Then change the plugin.xml of the FCM plugin to use a different version, in my situation 11.8.0. (inside /plugins/cordova-plugin-fcm/)

```
<framework src="com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0" />
<framework src="com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0" />
```

Now, remove en add the android platform again, so the changes will have affect. The next step is to just do ionic cordova run android

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer of @Kevin Dias, I searched among my plugins the string 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:+', which in my case was in the plugin phonegap-plugin-push
so what I did was:

```
ionic cordova platform remove android
ionic cordova platform add android
ionic cordova plugin remove phonegap-plugin-push
ionic cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-push --variable SENDER_ID="XXXXXXXXX" --variable FCM_VERSION="11.X.X"
ionic cordova build android
```

and the problems disappeared, so I can say that what we have to do is find out which plugin is given the error and try to update it.

**Edit 11/12/2018**

Finally, for me, this is not the main problem, I'm still looking for a solution, but maybe some of them will be solved. But it seems that something has happened with the maven repositories, like this:

- [Cannot run existing Android Project com.android.tools:common:25.3.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53677823/cannot-run-existing-android-project-com-android-toolscommon25-3-3)
- https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-image-picker/issues/1002

When it resolves, I will comment again on the solution.

**Edit 13/12/2018**

Finally it was a problem related to the disappearance of several plugins from jcenter libraries, according to the following link, https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/120759347#comment24

It seems that they have already solved it, and at least it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Adexe Rivera answer, I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the push notification plugin. Since the last version of the plugin requires the cordova-android package version to be >=7.0.0 I first uninstalled the android platform:

`ionic cordova platform rm android`

and installed it again but specifying that I wanted the latest cordova-android version available:

`ionic cordova platform add android@latest`.

After that, I added the push plugin again, specifying the SENDER_ID variable:

`ionic cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-push --variable SENDER_ID="XXXXXXXXXX"` and tried to build again.

This raised another error related to conflicting minSdkVersions. Doing some [research](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/minsdkversion-ignored-during-build/107118/5) it seems like another plugin, browsertab, specifies the minSdkVersion and it overrides the settings on the config.xml file at root folder. I changed that on the file created on root/platforms/android/cordova-plugin-browsertab so it matched the minSdkVersion I wanted (21) and finally it worked.

Hope this helps somebody.