# Could not find any matches for com.android.tools.build:gradle:+

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to build/run an ionic project but from today this error comes up and I could not find any answer.
Please, help me.

> Error: Could not find any matches for com.android.tools.build:gradle:+
>   as no versions of com.android.tools.build:gradle are available.

- Ionic Version: 4.5.0
- Cordova: 6.5.0
- NPM: 6.4.1
- Gradle: Gradle 4.10.2
- Kotlin DSL:   1.0-rc-6
- Kotlin:       1.2.61
- Groovy:       2.4.15
- Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.11 compiled on March 23 2018
- JVM:          1.8.0_191 (Oracle Corporation 25.191-b12)
- OS:           Windows 7 6.1 amd64

Answer (score 6):

On my specific case the problem was with fcm plugin, this was what I did:

- In platforms/android/build.gradle check buildscript gradle classpath version, my case was 2.2.3 (com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3)
- Then, in platforms/android/cordova-plugin-fcm/XXXX-FCMPlugin.gradle change classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:+' to the same version found above: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

That's it, fixed for me.

Comment: This worked for me as well for some reason it doesn't like the `+` anymore

Answer (score 4):

On my case i had this issue with the phonegap push plugin. I followed [@Niroog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53707674/ionic-build-throws-the-following-error-could-not-find-any-matches-for-com-andr/53714216#53714216) solution and and was able to solve it. Here is what i did:

- In platforms/android/build.gradle my gradle classpath version was 2.2.3
- I changed "classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:+' in "platform/android/phonegap-plugin-push/****-push.gradle" to "com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'" under dependencies

I saved and ran cmd "ionic cordova build android -prod" in terminal and it built successful.

Answer (score 3):

Facing the same issue since earlier today. The solutions above didn't work for me.
Came across another thread here...
https://forums.adobe.com/message/10804391#10804391

This one didnt work as well.Maybe I am doing something wrong..

----------EDIT-----------

Here is what worked for me

1) update build.gradle

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}..... 

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
    url "https://maven.google.com"
     }
}}
```

2) update cordova-plugin-fcm/xxxxxx-FCMPlugin.gradle

```
repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
    }
```

Inspired from: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin

Answer (score 2):

My issue was with the `intercom-cordova-plugin` which requires version 2.2.3 currently.

I just started getting this error today as well. Not 100% sure why, but maybe check your platforms/android/ directory for any plugins *.gradle files that are trying to include the version of gradle that's not found.

Updating cordova-plugin-intercom/mtg-intercom.gradle to use 3.1.0 got it working again. I suspect something went wrong with a remote maven/gradle repository, and we're seeing some downstream effects.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, @Niroog. Your solution works and I voted up for your answer. But the solution works only for Cordova android version 6.3.0 and greater. In my case, I had two projects:

- Project 1: Cordova android version 6.3.0,
- Project 2: Cordova android version 6.2.3

For Project 1, the solution given by @Niroog above works fine.

But if someone using version 6.2.3, Here is the solution:-

Step 1:

```
ionic cordova platform rm android
ionic cordova platform add android@6.3.0 // or greater
ionic cordova prepare android
```

Step 2:
Follow @Niroog's solution above. And build now

```
ionic cordova build android
```

If you still face an error follow step 3. Because in my case after upgrading to 6.3.0, "**cordova-plugin-push**" folder was generated automatically. So I have to repeat the same solution for `push.gradle` file too.

Step 3:

In `platforms/android/cordova-plugin-push/XXXX-push.gradle` change `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:+'` to the same version found above: `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'`

Then `ionic cordova build android`

Answer (score 1):

```
subprojects {
    if (project.name.startsWith('react-native-')){
        buildscript {
            repositories {
                jcenter()
                maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools/"  }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Try above work around.