# Android Studio reading data from excel?

Tags: android-studio, import-from-excel

i was wondering if there is any effecient way to read data from an Excel file in Android Studio. I have tried aspose - cells but it dosn't seem to work for me...

Comment: What problems do you have with the Aspose API?  It should work fine.

Comment: Well it might just be me that can't add it correctly to my project (i am kinda new to Android Studio), but as soon as i add it as a jar library, Android Studio refuses to run my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not positive if this will fix your specific issue or not, but I saw someone post similar problems on Aspose's forums here ([Aspose Cells doesn't work in Android Studio 1.0](http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/thread/600487/aspose-cells-doesn-t-work-in-android-studio-1.0.aspx))

Their solution was:

> Hi, I found a solution, I increased heap size (https://stackoverflow.com/a/16634014). I created a new environment
>   variable named _JAVA_OPTIONS, set it to -Xms256m -Xmx2048m.

Looks like it ended up referring back to another Stack Overflow question.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Okay i tried your sugestion and created that variable, and while it didn't fix my problem it at least didn't give me any errors while trying to run the application. Now it says ADB not responding instead.

Comment: after this i set the variable to a lot of diffrent values that was sugestet in the Stack Overflow post, but all of them seemed to cause the same problem, and to all my application not only the one with Aspose.

Comment: what operating system are you using?

Comment: Even after removing the variable it still says ADB not responding i think i might accidentally have run into a completly unrelated problem.

Comment: I have no idea what caused the ADB to not respond put after fideling with the variable for some time i finaly got it to work. both the ADB and the Aspose application. thanks alot for the help.