# Android-Studio : Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine. A fatal Exception Occurred

Tags: java, android, android-studio, heap-memory

I have installed Android studio today. Now When I am trying to import my existing project which work previously in other PC, just getting error as shown in below image.

[image]

I also tried from [Android-Studio : Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16589585/android-studio-error-could-not-create-the-java-virtual-machine). If any other solution than please let me know about these.

My System Description.
Window 7, 32-bit, 3GB RAM

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/430853/error-could-not-create-the-java-virtual-machine-error-a-fatal-exception-has-o

Comment: I already tried dude. `-Xmx4g` what does it means I set `Xmx512M` or `Xmx1024M`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to use 4GB of memory use `-Xmx4096m`

Comment: But have 3GB RAM only. Where Can i change these

Comment: In the hardware store.

Comment: @vucko LOL, but you can use paging memory for increasing the base memory. On a serious note, higunjan check your JAVA_OPTS

Comment: @AvinashR yeah, but 3 gigs is not enough for Android development. He's never gonna have  a good time with emulator eating at least 1/3 of that and Android studio 0.5GB. I have 16 GB and a constant memory usage of ~40ish%.

Comment: That's another problem @vucko

Comment: I have 3GB Memory now from that I have to use 1G for running my app in Nexus build fails Reason was above.

Answer (score 0):

This is a memory error. Seems like you have to increase the memory size as you have listed that your PC has only 3GB RAM. You have to physically increase the RAM and then increase the heap size for Android Studio using the following guide :

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration

Android Studio System Requirements page says only 2GB is needed as a minimum. So you may be able to run it if you follow the above guide and increase the heap size Android Studio uses.

But in the long run I highly recommend increasing the RAM, as 4GB is the recommended size and without that much you will encounter many lags and problems such as very high Gradle build times.

Comment: Try running on 2GB and tell me! Like any other System Requirements, it tells the minimum memory for *running* not for *using*.